# Test PHP's mail function from localhost

Tags: php, email, testing, localhost

I need to test a function that uses PHP's mail()
How can I do this without uploading the script to a server and test it online?
What's even more I am developing with no Internet connection at all.
I am on Mac OSX running localhost from XAMPP.

Comment: Can't you just run your script from localhost?

Answer (score 54):

You don't have to install an MTA on your computer to test PHP's `mail()` function. On Unix based systems (Linux, *BSD, OS X, etc.) you can set `sendmail_path` to something like `tee mail.out > /dev/null`. This will put the emails (including the headers) in a file called `mail.out`.

Here is an example of how it would work:

```
daniel@daniel-laptop:~$ cat | php -d sendmail_path='tee mail.out > /dev/null'
<?php
mail('test@example.com', 'the subject', 'the body');
?>
daniel@daniel-laptop:~$ cat mail.out
To: test@example.com
Subject: the subject
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:-


the body
```

You can set `sendmail_path` in your `php.ini` file. If you want to append emails to the file instead of overwriting each time, you can use `tee -a` instead of just `tee`.

Comment: wish I saw this before I spent ages figuring out how to get sendmail/postfix working

Comment: Can I read this file with an email client? In my case I'm using `tee -a`

Comment: Is `tee file.txt > /dev/null` any better than `cat >> file.txt` ? Is there some reason that I don't see to prefer to use `tee`?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this guarantees that it is going to work on a real server.

Answer (score 11):

To test sending email from apache do the following

create a folder to store the email.

```
/home/username/Documents/TestEmails
```

Give permission to apache. From the Documents folder, run

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data TestEmails
```

Modify the php.ini file, mine is located at

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

set sendmail_path

```
sendmail_path ='cat > /home/username/Documents/TestEmails/mail.txt'
```

Restart apace2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: What if I'm using the MAMP server software for developing on localhost?

Comment: Best answer which worked for me is the one below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3176517/1130803), as it uses `tee` instead of `cat` which gives an `Invalid argument` error in OSX. If using MAMP, I guess the same advice applies, only changing the path to where your php.ini is.

Comment: This is working for me, but just from CLI scripts; but not from a web service. Is there something else I need to do aside of restarting apache?

Comment: If you use `cat >> /path/mail.txt` instead of `cat > /path/mail.txt`, it will append the mail rather than overwriting it. This can be useful if, say, you are debugging where you send a mail to a call center as well as the customer, for example.

Answer (score 5):

A nice and simple solution for testing:

<strike>http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/</strike>
Updated link:
https://github.com/ifunk/smtp-catcher

Comment: There is a small Windows section at the end of the page. On other Unix systems I think you could solve it similarly to the Mac case.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I haven't tried this, but in php.ini you can set "sendmail_path" ... so in theory you could write your own shell script that simply wrote the input into text files, and change your php.ini to use that? Then simply run tests and check text files!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows/using something like WAMP/UWAMP/XAMPP and need to test mail then Papercut is well worth a look:

https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut

You can leave your SMTP settings in php.ini as the defaults (localhost/25) and it just works. It looks like an email client and shows all the parts of/details of a message in separate sections.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a pop3 server in local Machine. Many available for free.
and send mails within your local domain using sendmail.

By default its not required to set the sendmail path in Linux. at least I never needed it.
just use the mail() function and hit mails on local domain

Comment: That would be a SMTP server buddy pop3 is to actually receive emails not send mails out.

Comment: LOL Ya But where would the sendmail send the mails ???????????
he have no internet connection.
Okay ??????
Thats the reasonhe needs a POP3 Server to run a local test.

>> we are not talking about SMTP server. its sendmail

Comment: having access to the machine as he does with only the mail server he can verify it without having to go thru a pop3 connection.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer @Daniel-Egeberg provided, this is what worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

I opened /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini and set:

sendmail_path='tee /path/to/file/mail.out'

restarted:

sudo service apache2 restart

then created /path/to/file/mail.out and changed permissions for it:

chmod 666 /path/to/file/mail.out