# function mail() in php is not working

Tags: php, email

I m trying to send an email through php, but it doesnt work

```html
// the message
    $Message = "Hello World";

// send email
    mail('XXXXX@hotmail.com',"Welcome",$Message, "From:" . $SenderEmail); // $SenderEmail is defined before
```

Comment: if your sending through local host check your spam box

Comment: i did!, nothing there

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342822/php-mail-function-on-localhost

Comment: better use php mailer for sending mail

Comment: `mail()` will not send if you are using a localhost **unless** you set up a local mail server. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175488/test-phps-mail-function-from-localhost). on how.