# Make mail() of PHP work under localhost of Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, phpmailer

I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78wFR5Rp_Mw) to configure localhost in my Mac OS X El Capitan.

I have modified `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (eg, made `/Users/softtimur` as `DocumentRoot` and `Directory`), `/etc/apache2/users/softtimur.conf` and created `/etc/php.ini`.

Now if I write a simple `/Users/softtimur/Home.html`, I could load it in a browser by `localhost/Home.html`; loading `phpinfo()` in a PHP file does show the PHP configuration page in a browser.

However, in a terminal the result of `apachectl -S` is NOT `Virtual Host configuration: Syntax OK` as the video shows:

```
:Site $ apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40)
         port 443 namevhost localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:121)
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/softtimur"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="softtimur" id=501 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

Does anyone know if there is anything wrong?

To set `sendmail_path`, I have followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19625975/702977):
1) created a folder to store the email: `/home/softtimur/Documents/TestEmails`;
2) gave permission to apache: run `sudo chgrp -R _www TestEmails` from the Documents folder
3) modified `php.ini`: `sendmail_path ='cat > /home/softtimur/Documents/TestEmails/mail.txt'`

And then, I wrote a file `testmail.php`:

```
<?php
mail('mymail@gmail.com', 'the subject', 'the body');
?>
```

But loading the page did not send me any mail.

Does anyone know what's wrong in the whole process?

Comment: I do not recommend using the mail function. I suggest using something like pear or phpmailer.

Comment: On El Capitan run `apachectl configtest` to check config syntax. Using `cat` in `sendmail_path` will not send any email, it is just for testing, see quoted thread.