# Using "tee…" as sendmail_path in php results in an extra file when using "-f"-parameter.

Tags: php, tee

I'm using what I learned over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3176517/ to route mail()-commands in PHP on my local machine to a file. From the `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path ='tee /testmail/mail.txt'
```

But when I add an `additional_parameter` (`-fwebmaster@example.com`) it generates an addtional file named `-fwebmaster@example.com` with the content of the mail in the current folder.

A complete example:

```
$ cat | php -d sendmail_path='tee /testmail/mail.txt'
<?php
mail('test@example.com', 'subject', 'body', '', '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
To: test@example.com
Subject: subject


body
```

The last five lines are written to `/testmail/mail.txt` *and* and newly created `-fwebmaster@example.com`.

It seems that the `-f`-parameter gets forwarded to the `tee`-command. Is there a way to prevent that?

(Using `cat` results in an error and PHP returns `false`.)

Comment: what *else* would the parameter get passed to?

Comment: Ideally it would be ignored in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore any additional arguments passed from php by wrapping your command in a shell script:

**pseudo_sendmail**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tee /testmail/mail.txt
```

PHP config:

```
sendmail_path ='/path/to/pseudo_sendmail'
```

Comment: Just want I wanted. This means I can even write
`#!/usr/bin/env bash
tee /testmail/mail.txt
cp /testmail/mail.txt /testmail/mail.eml`
to simultaneously create a "real" email for easier previewing.